# Получение всех цветов в список C#

Tags: c#

Делаю игру, и столкнулся с проблемой. Я использую Colorful.Console чтобы использовать вместо ConsoleColor System.Drawing.Color. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы в консоль выводились все цвета которые есть в Color. Вот как я пытался это вывести:
Метод GetAllColors:

```
public static List<Color> GetAllColors()
        {
            List<Color> aallColors = new List<Color>();

            foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(Color).GetProperties())
            {
                if (property.PropertyType == typeof(Color))
                {
                    aallColors.Add((Color)property.GetValue(null));
                }
            }

            return aallColors;
        }
```

И вот вывод:

```
Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("Введите цвет:");
allColors = GetAllColors();
for(int i = 1; i < allColors.Count(); i++)
{
    try
    {
        Colorful.Console.Write(allColors[i].Name + " ", allColors[i]);
    }
    catch { }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Консоль выводит это:
[image: Почти все цвета просто бежевые...]

Comment: А вы уверены, что консоль умеет отображать все цвета, что доступны в System.Drawing.Color?

Comment: *Colorful.Console can only write to the console in 16 different colors* — это из описания библиотеки

Comment: Да, я сейчас попробовал жёлтый цвет отдельно  и он работал, а на картинке он бежевый...

Comment: _Write with full System.Drawing.Color support_ тоже там написано

Comment: Ну так да, ты можешь использовать любой цвет, но в рамках одной сессии только 16 из-за ограничения виндовой консоли

Comment: Можно как-то это ограничение увеличить?

Comment: Зачем эти мучения? Просто используйте GUI-приложение (WinForms или WPF).

Comment: @Lenator некоторые терминалы поддерживают 256 цветов. Но если вы будете ориентироваться на них, ваша игра не будет кроссплатформенной, в том числе не будет работать на винде. Если вы делаете игру Roguelike, либо используйте 16 цветов, как в этом жанре принято, либо используйте существующий графический движок для вывода символов (я свой рогалик в monogame делал, например)

Comment: Было принято решение использовать 16 цветов. Спасибо за советы.

Comment: 16 цветов одновремменно в полноэкранном режиме поддерживаются апаратно, это обойти нельзя. В оконном режиме можно получить HWND окна, взять его DC и рисовать как угодно и какими угодно цветами (я рисовал) - но это усложнит программу в разы, а в полноекранном режиме безполезно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Было принято решение использовать 16 цветов.